# Ubuntu server 14.04 kernel panic at boot

Tags: kernel

Since when I installed netatalk on Ubuntu server 14.04 I get a kernel panic at boot. I think netatalk is the cause because I can see the word "appletalk" many times in the kernel panic screen. I've also changed both my RAM modules and checked my HDD, CPU and GPU to be sure that the kernel panic was not caused by a hardware failure. I tried booting with a different kernel and the situation didn't change, while booting in rescue mode didn't result in a kernel panic. However, I got a kernel panic even in rescue mode after issuing the `dpkg --configure -a` command.

I really don't know what to do and I don't understand much from the kernel panic screen. Here is it; I hope you can help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue with when I upgraded my Ubuntu server from 12.04 to 14.04. It's caused by a bug in the kernel, and [a fix was released today](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/linux/+bug/1356913). You should be able to fix it with

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```